# Unable to change color in R in a USA map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the background colors in US map for displaying presidential results for different states. I read so many posts regarding this color change but I was not able to change any of those colors. Below is my code, link for dataset and snapshot which I am getting:

```
#install.packages("ggplot2")
#install.packages("ggmap")
#install.packages("plyr")
#install.packages("raster")
#install.packages("stringr")

library(ggplot2) # for plotting and miscellaneuous things
library(ggmap) # for plotting
library(plyr) # for merging datasets
library(raster) # to get map shape filegeom_polygon
library(stringr) # for string operation

# Get geographic data for USA
usa.shape<-getData("GADM", country = "usa", level = 1)   

# Creating a data frame of map data
usa.df <- map_data("state")    

#rename 'region' as 'state' and make it a factor variable 
colnames(usa.df) [5] <- "State"
usa.df$State <- as.factor(usa.df$State)

#set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/Ashish/Documents/Stats projects/2/")

#input data from file separated by  commas
usa.dat <- read.csv("data1.csv", header = T)

# printing data structure
str(usa.df)

# removing % sign from the data, and converting percentage win to numeric
usa.dat$Clinton <- as.numeric(sub("%","",usa.dat$Clinton))/1
usa.dat$Trump <- as.numeric(sub("%","",usa.dat$Trump))/1
usa.dat$Others <- as.numeric(sub("%","",usa.dat$Others))/1


# Creating a winner column based on the percentage 
usa.dat$Winner = "Trump"
usa.dat[usa.dat$Clinton > usa.dat$Trump,]$Winner = "Clinton"
usa.dat$State <- tolower(usa.dat$State)

# Creating a chance column which corresponds to winning percentage of the         candidate
usa.dat$chance <- usa.dat$Trump
a <- usa.dat[usa.dat$Clinton > usa.dat$Trump,]
usa.dat[usa.dat$Clinton > usa.dat$Trump,]$chance <- a$Clinton

# display the internal structure of the object
usa.dat

#join the usa.df and usa.dat objects on state variable
usa.df <- join(usa.df, usa.dat, by = "State", type = "inner")

str(usa.df)
states <- data.frame(state.center, state.abb) # centers of states and abbreviations

#function for plotting different regions of USA map based on the input data       showing different coloring scheme 
#for each state.
p <- function(data, title) {
  ggp <- ggplot() +
    #       Draw borders of states
    geom_polygon(data = data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, 
                              fill = Winner, alpha=chance), color = "black", size = 0.15) + 


#scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0,1))+
scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("#F08080","white","#5DADE2"),breaks = c(0,50,100), 
                      labels=c("Clinton","Equal","Trump"),
                      limits=c(0,100),name="Election Forecast") +

#       Add state abbreviations     
geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb), size = 2)+
guides(fill = guide_legend(direction='vertical',  title='Candidate', label=TRUE, colours=c("red", "blue")))
  return(ggp)
}

figure.title <- "2016 presidential election result"

# Save the map to a file to viewing (you can plot on the screen also, but it takes
# much longer that way. The ratio of US height to width is 1:9.)
#print(p(usa.df, brks.to.use, figure.title))

ggsave(p(usa.df, figure.title), height = 4, width = 4*1.9,
       file = "election_result.jpg")
```

Image link: [image: USA map as my output]

Dataset: [Dataset link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNs80hwMGUReGduSGJvSkhBUVU/view?usp=sharing)

I would like to get same coloring scheme as displayed in Election forecast gradient.

Comment: You're using `scale_color_gradientn`, when you want to adjust fill. Use `scale_fill_gradientn` instead. It looks like the data mapped to fill is binary, though, so you may actually just need `scale_fill_discrete` (or `_manual`, `_brewer`, etc.; just not `_continuous` derivatives).

Comment: @alistaire: Thanks for update. But I am till seeing no change. Use of 
    `scale_fill_discrete` won't change anything as such here.

Comment: Also, I think although we have binary color scheme, each of those color scheme is also continuous if you closely observe here.

Comment: You've really not made it easy for folks to help you. "Do manual operations in a spreadsheet" and a gdocs link. Seriously not reproducible and not respectful of volunteer time.

Comment: I'd probably use `scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 6)`. As you have it currently structured, fill is discrete, but alpha (opacity) is continuous. You could combine those into a single scale, which _would_ be a continuous fill, but that would require rearranging your data.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: and others: Sorry for the previous Dataset link. I have modified that link. It now points to the exact dataset I am using in my code. You can download it from this link and provide the path. It should work. Apologies, again!

Comment: @alistaire: Great! That worked like a charm!In the original code, I added the line you told after ggplot and it works. I tried it previously as well before posting here, but I wasn't using type property then; hence I dropped that idea then. Can you provide your solution below so that I can mark it as accepted answer? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alistaire for providing his valuable feedbacks and solution for the above problem. Using `scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 6)` along with `ggplot()` resolves the above issue in R.